# Cant host content with amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

here is what i have done:

I've opened up post 80, 22,21 in the amazon e2 security settings

i have putty and putty gen

i have putty and pem keys

i created an index.html file in the public_html directory using Win_SCP

nothing loads

http://ec2-107-20-57-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Putty keeps telling me the connection refuses no matter what i put in it. 
I can't even login without it disconnecting me. Is this a problem with my own network setting at work , is this a problem with putty config, problem with my amazon account..i dunno

Comment: When you say you have "opened" those ports, how did you open them?  Did you allow access only from certain IP's?  can you post information from your security policy into your question so that can be reviewed?

Answer (score 0):

First, 
What IP addresses did you allow HTTP, FTP and SSH traffic from?

Next, 
Is ec2-107-20-57-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com still the correct instance name?

Then, 
Is your web started and running? 
Is index.html the actual default document?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with instances refusing connections. I would suggest you to check the ports open and if they allow the traffic from all IPs. Also, if you are using the default security settings and it refuses the connections, try creating your custom security profile and open up the required ports and allow IPs.

Also, which OS image did you select while creating the instance?